# Water coming in through weep holes during hard rain?

Tags: walls, brick, exterior, weep-hole

One room in the front of our house leaks during a hard driving rain storms.  The leaks are at the top of the window and at the floor -- both locations which seem to correspond to locations of weep holes in the exterior brick veneer.

Here is a picture of where it leaks at the top of the window.

[image]

Here is a picture of the weep holes:

[image]

My question: is it possible the rain is being driven into the weep holes?  Or is this more likely clogged weep holes?  Or is this an issue with the way it was built?

Bonus question: This house has a 10 year structural warranty from the builder and we are in year 9.  Is this type of repair (to fix the exterior such that it stops leaking) the kind of thing that would be covered under such a warranty?

Comment: Just an FYI. We have the same situation with our home and the structural warranty does not cover this. We had the builder come out before just after the initial warranty ran out and they reworked the area in question. Now, three years later, the same issue reappeared, and it is not covered under the 10yr structural warranty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"is it possible the rain is being driven into the weep holes?"

- yes, but the weep holes are supposed to be on the outside of a moisture barrier, so rain driven in still should not enter the house.

"is this more likely clogged weep holes?"

- no, the holes are designed to "weep", and are difficult to completely clog.

"is this an issue with the way it was built?"

- yes, I suspect a structural defect such as incorrectly installed flashing above the window or inadequate/incorrectly installed moisture barrier.

You absolutely should pursue repairs through the builder's warranty.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is too late to reply on this. Its the exact issue we have. There seems to be a hole exactly at the peak of the roof which the handyman says causing the water to enter the house. Check the roof in such situations